# Desecrating Shabbos to ask a Gadol to daven for a patient?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Can you desecrate Shabbos by sending a letter/leaving the Techum to ask a Gadol to daven for a patient whose life is in immediate danger?

Comment: Re. sources, see Yabia Omer Vol. 8 OC §37 and you’ll be covered.

Comment: What is "sending a letter"?

Comment: Is it alongside the medical treatment or instead?

Comment: @AlBerko Thankfully this isn't a real question otherwise CYLOR - but for the purposes of this question you can answer either way. Questioning whether a gadol's tefillos works for medical treatment seems to be a separate question

Comment: I'd say, in the lack of any clear requirements for treatment to count as "justifying" for Hillul Shabbos, whether scientific or superstitious, everyone follows his guts. That's Heftza (treatments). As for the Gavra (the person herself), as we see with childbirth, if that makes her happy and eases the pain, it already counts as treatment (and therefore justifies Hilul Shabbos).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R' Shlomo Kluger in Shu"t U’vacharta BaChaim ([§87](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=781&pgnum=122)) vehemently forbade such practice, after an incident where a local Rav permitted a *kvittel* to be written and sent to the Belzer Rebbe on Shabbos.

The *Eshel Avraham* ([328.17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36229&st=&pgnum=59)) quotes a *yesh omrim* that it is forbidden, but leaves off 'וצ״ע'

> דלכתוב שיבא אוהבו אצלו או שיתפללו בעדו י"ל דאסור וצלע"ע היטב

However, there were *poskim* who permitted such activity. The Kaf Hachaim ([306:77](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.306.77.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) quotes the Pesach Ha’Dvir who permitted in a very similar case:

> וכתב הפתה"ד או' טו"ב מעשה שאירע בזמן המגפה ש' התקע"ד שניגף ראו' ביום
>   ש"ק בתוך העיר ושמעון אחיו היה בכפר והחולה היה מצטער הרבה על שלא נמצא
>   אחיו אצלו ואין לו ידיעה מחליו שרצונו היה שיתפלל על רפואתו וגם היה רוצה
>   לצוות על בניו הקטנים הי"ו וכראות גיסו של הניגף צרת נפשו קרא לסופר תוגר
>   וצוהו שיכתוב כתב בל' תוגרמא לשמעון הנז' העומד בכפר להודיעו כי נשבה
>   אחיו וניגף ושיעשה לו שם בכפר איזה לימוד והתפלה והצעקה והצדקה מבטלין
>   הגזרה וכן עשה התוגר והגיע הכתב בשבת ליד שמעון. וכתב שם הפתה"ד **דאין בזה
>   נדנוד איסור יעו"ש** ומה שהביא סמוכות לזה:

There is a similar ruling from the *Shoel U'Meishiv* ([Telisaah, V2 §180](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shoel_uMeshiv_Mahadura_III.2.180.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)), allowing relatives to transgress Shabbos in order to be by the bedside of dying family members. He explains his reasoning:

> והנה בשנת תרי"ג נשאלתי מאחד מפה לבוב **שבא לו ידיעה שאשתו תקיף לה עלמא**
>   בטריסקאוויטץ סמוך לדראהביטש **ונשאלתי אם מותר לנסוע שמה**. והשבתי ד**נראה
>   לפענ"ד דמותר** דהרי מבואר בש"ע או"ח סי' ש"י ס"ט והוא מהג"א פ"ק דב"ב
>   ובהגמ' פ"ב דהלכות אישות בחולה שתקיף לי' עלמא **ומבקש שישלחו אחר אוהבי'
>   דמותר לשלח רץ בשבת כדי שלא תטרוף דעתו** ואף דשם אינו רק אמירה לעכו"ם
>   שבות וכאן הישראל יסע בשבת מכל מקום הא רכיבה בשבת ג"כ אינו רק שבות
>   ועיין מג"א סי' רס"ו ס"ק ז' וסי' ש"ה סעיף י"ח בהג"ה ועיין בחו"מ סי'
>   רנ"ד דקונין משכ"מ בשבת אף שא"צ כדי שלא תטרוף דעתו עליו והוא מריש הזורק
>   ובב"ב דף קנ"ד ע"ב. ובפרט שהוא בכפר או בעיר שאין לה מכיר שמה דבודאי
>   תהנה אם יבא בעלה וא"כ ספק פיקוח נפש דוחה שבת ואף דהתוס' ריש פרק הזורק
>   כתבו דאין מתירין שאר השבות רק הקניה בשבת מכל מקום **נראה לפענ"ד דכל שהוא
>   לצורך החולה מתירין כל שבות** וע"כ התרתי ונתתי כתב בידו כדי שלא יהיה
>   חילול השם **ומכל מקום בעת רוכבו צויתי לו שלא ילבש בדרך שיכירו בו שהוא
>   יהודי כדי שלא יהי' חילול השם דאטו יראה לכל ההיתר כנלפענ"ד**. ואם תרצה
>   לדעת **כמה גדול כח שכיב מרע שחשו שלא תטרף דעתו עליו בא וראה מ"ש הרא"ש**
>   וכן קי"ל בסימן שכ"ח שהתירו לשחוט לחולה שיש בו סכנה אף שיש נבילה מוכן
>   שמא יקוץ החולה ויסתכן כמ"ש הרא"ש **וא"כ חזינן שהתירו בשביל צער החולה
>   מכ"ש להתיר שבות בשביל צער החולה ואף ששם יש לחוש שיסתכן גם כאן יש לחוש
>   כן כנלפענ"ד**

The Maharsham supposedly (I heard this in a *shiur*, but have never seen it myself) writes that it would be permitted to be *mechallel shabbos* to send a message to someone who is renowned for the effectiveness of his *tefilla* and *bracha*, although his final ruling is to forbid in feeble generations like ours.

There are other sources for permitting *chillul shabbos* במקום פיקוח נפש, even for mystical assitance. The Chida (Birkei Yosef OCH 301, YD 290; Chaim Sha'al 2:36) cites a tradition he had that Rabbeinu Peretz (of the Ba'alei Tosfos) wrote a *kimeiya* on Shabbos for a woman in difficult childbirth, and he quotes a ruling from the רמ"ה (one of the Rishonim) permitting this. R' Chaim Palag'i (*Refuah v'Chaim* Perek 12) writes that R' Shalom Sharabi once wrote a *kimeiya* on Shabbos.

In summary, there are two reasons why some permit it: (a) Fulfilling the wishes of a חולה שיש בו סכנה is necessary to preserve his frame of mind, because agitation could prove be detremental; (b) In certain circumstances, even mystical השתדלות is permitted under פיקוח נפש.

Others - and, I believe, the mainstream accepted *halacha* - is that it is forbidden to desecrate Shabbos for spiritual and mystical *hishtadlus*; *pikuach nefesh* only permits practical scientific *hishtadlus*.

---

*Edit: I found the Maharsham ([Chelek Gimmel, Siman 225](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1527&st=&pgnum=225)). He writes the story and the various responses, as well as adding that the Belzer Rebbe was angry, that he was now 'forced to perform a miracle' in order that it should not be Chillul Shabbos. He did recover.*

Comment: Very interesting variety of answers on this question. I'm curious how you - 1) knew where to look and 2) How you located some of these "obscure" sources. I haven't heard of a few of these "sefarim".

Comment: @DanF They’re all referenced in the source cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105695/desecrating-shabbos-for-supernatural-medicine#comment353542_105695). (Which are “obscure” (sic) that you haven’t heard of?)

Comment: Which of these sefarim haven't you heard of (other than R' Chaim Palagi's Refuah Vchaim, maybe)? I heard a shiur some time back; I've seen writeups of the story in גליונות... There are plenty of מלקטים around who love this type of thing... Once you have one or two *mareh mokomos*, the rest follow after a bit of easy research.

Comment: Just did a bit of searching... For those interested, see [this writeup](http://olamot.net/sites/default/files/pdf/88.pdf) from olamot. There are a bunch more mekoros from rishonim and poskim that I wasn't aware of...